# How to print a message only once in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I am using for loops combined with if statements to read integers from a text file into a two-dimensional array.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
            inFile >> ArrB[i][j];
            if (ArrB[i][j] == -1) {
                bad = true;
                cout << "The array does not have enough integers" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (ArrB[i][j] < 1) {
                    invalidnum = true;
                }
            }

            if (invalidnum = true) {
                cout << *(*(ArrB + i) + j) << " ";
                cout << "There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array imported from your text file." << endl;

            }
        }
    }
```

This code will read in the first 6 integers (max_row * max_column) from a text file into ArrB.

If  -1 exists in the first 6 integers, it will exit the loop and print out "The array does not have enough integers".

If there is no -1 in the first 6 integers, then it will check all 6 integers to see if there are any other negative numbers or zero.

If there are negative numbers or zero, I want it to still print out the array, then print out the error message (There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array imported from your text file) ONLY ONCE.

For example, this is my text file. As you can see, there is no -1 in the first 6 numbers, but there is a -7.

[image]

So, ideally, the result should be something like:

```
2 4 5 6 9 -7

There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array imported from your text file
```

But this is what I am getting if I run my code above:

[image]

-------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

Figured it out based on @ZedLepplin 's comment

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
            inFile >> ArrB[i][j];
            if (ArrB[i][j] == -1) {
                bad = true;
                cout << "The array does not have enough integers" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (ArrB[i][j] < 1) {
                    invalidnum = true;
                }
            }
            cout << *(*(ArrB + i) + j) << " ";
        }
    }
    if (invalidnum == true) {
        cout << "There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array imported from your text file." << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please post text as text not as image. `invalidnum = true` is not `invalidnum == true`, is it a typo?

Comment: change this `if (invalidnum = true)` to this `if (invalidnum == true)`

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I edited my question according to your comments. Once I changed = to ==, the error message will only get print out once, but now it's not printing the whole array....

Comment: Put the conditional error message print after your for loop. Leave the cout for displaying the array number inside the for loop so it is output for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I was making an edit but you got in very quickly, does the edit make any difference?

Comment: @ZedLepplin Thank you! It worked! Would you like to post the previous comment as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Note your `break` will not stop all loops only inner one, you need to use flag or better put those 2 loops in a function and use `return` instead of `break`

Comment: @Slava aha, didn't notice that, thank you!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks! :) I figured out how to use the breakpoint based on the comments from the other post.Btw, the link you shared is no longer valid...it shows 404 Page Not Found

Comment: Here you go, just added to pastebin [Reading & Checking Arrays C++](https://pastebin.com/JVrXeJvw)

Comment: Simplified and updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the conditional error message print after your for loop. Leave the cout for displaying the array number inside the for loop so it is output for every iteration of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<MAX_ROWS;i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
        inFile >> ArrB[i][j];
        if (ArrB[i][j] == -1) {
            bad = true;
            cout << "The array does not have enough integers" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            if (ArrB[i][j] < 1) {
                invalidnum = true;
            }
        }

        cout << * (*(ArrB + i) + j) << " ";
    }
}

if (invalidnum = true) {
        cout << "There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array imported from your text file." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a counter, and put the message outside of the loop.
Something like :

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS ; i++) {
    if(myVector[i] == -1) {
        counter++;
    }
    else {
    // Do normal stuff
    }
}
if(counter > 0) {
    cout << "The array contained " << counter << "negative values" << endl;
}
```

Ho, and I'd advise to avoid comparisons to "true". If myVar is a boolean alrady, I can just do `if(myVar)`. No need to do `if(myVar == true)`.
And doing `if(myVar = true)` is worse, as it sets myVar to true, regardless of its initial value. That's a common typo that can be hard to detect when proofreading code.

Edited version (to adapt to comments) :

```
bool earlyNegativeOneFound = false;
int otherNegativeCounter;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS ; i++) {
        if(i < 6 && myVector[i] == -1) {
            earlyNegativeOneFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else if(myVector[i] < 0) {
            cout << myVector[i] << endl;
            otherNegativeCounter++;
        }
        else {
        // Do normal stuff
        }
    }
    if(!earlyNegativeOneFound  && otherNegativeCounter> 0) {
        cout << "The array contained " << otherNegativeCounter << "negative values" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But this is slightly different than I was asking. Your code sets counter to 0, and increase the counter if there is -1 in the array, then print out how many counter (nagative ones) in the array.

Comment: What I need to do is: Stop the program if there is a -1 in the first 6 integers. If there is no -1, but any other nagative numbers in the array, print out the array, and print out the error message.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly what you're trying to do. I edited my answer to provide the behavior you just described. Now if a -1 is found in the first 6 value of the vector, everything stops. Otherwise, you'll get a message saying how many negative numbers were found once the loop is over. Also prints the negative values along the way when finding them.

Comment: Basically, I wasn't trying to count how many nagative numbers (other than nagative 1) are there in the array. I was trying to print out the whole array (both positive numbers and negative numbers) even if the nagative numbers exist. Then print out the error message

Comment: Thank you for the comment though, your algorithm is definitely helpful

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you meant

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
            flag log = false;
            inFile >> ArrB[i][j];
            if (ArrB[i][j] == -1) {
                bad = true;
                cout << "The array does not have enough integers" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (ArrB[i][j] < 1) {
                    invalidnum = true;
                }
            }

            if (invalidnum = true) {
                cout << *(*(ArrB + i) + j) << " ";
                if(!flag)
                {

                     cout << "There is/are negative number(s) or zero(s) in the array 
                              imported from your text file." << endl;
                     flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding the flag boolean variable would allow the statement "there are negative numbers.." to be printed once.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the message and print it where and when you want. Some psuedo-code:

```
std::string message;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j< M; ++j)
    {
        if (smth)
        {
            message {"Your message"};
            break; // note that after break,
                   // you are still in the outer loop
        }
        else if (smth else)
        {
            message {"Your message"};
        }
    }
    // print it here
}
// or here, or wherever you want to
```